# How to group overlapping data in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I have data in following fashion

```
Prog_Id Low_latency  Max_Latency
a        1            4
a       -1            5
a        3            8
a       11           12
a       12           15
```

Now I wish to see output as

```
Prog_Id  Low_latency   Max_Latency
a          -1            8
a          11            15
```

Basically I wish to merge overlapping data. Can anyone help me with the code. I can manage time at the place of latency, if there is  a solution with OVERLAPS clause.

Thanks 
Rishabh

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle?

Comment: Please explain the the expected output.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'am using Vertica. It excepts all sql based queries.

Comment: Are you trying to merge the intervals, so that [-1, 5] and [3, 8] becomes [-1, 8] ?

Comment: @AdityaJain In o/p I  need to see minimum latency and maximum latency for overlapping intervals. In above example there can be two such intervals.

Comment: @FarukSahin Yes. But I need to consider 1 and 4 also. As it lies in same range although doesn't contribute in final o/p

Answer (score 1):

My initial answer was not always working. Now it looks like it is:

```
select distinct *
from (
   select
     t1.Prog_ID,
     min(least(l, Low_latency)),
     max(greatest(g, Max_Latency))
   from yourtable t1 inner join (select
                                   t1.Prog_ID,
                                   least(t1.Low_latency, t2.Low_latency) l,
                                   greatest(t1.Max_Latency, t2.Max_Latency) g
                                 from
                                   yourtable t1 inner join yourtable t2
                                   on t1.Prog_ID=t2.Prog_ID
                                      and t1.Low_latency<=t2.Max_Latency
                                      and t1.Max_Latency>=t2.Low_Latency) t2
     on t1.Prog_ID=t2.Prog_ID
        and t1.Low_latency<=t2.g
        and t1.Max_Latency>=t2.l
   group by t1.Low_latency, t1.Max_latency) s
```

please see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f1b6/11). It's MySql code but can be converted for other DBMS.

Comment: Great solution! I advaned the test, i realy works! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f1b6/1/0

Comment: @GreenRover There should have only four rows in o/p -1 to 8; 11 to 18 and 22 to 25; and 32 to 35

Comment: @user1929950 thanks, I corrected my answer, now i think it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which databse server (DBMS) you use. But there is no easy solution for. There could be a possibility to use [Stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) . But I would prefer to do this in a programming language (which language do you use?)

After testing some around with querys of other people, I found no way in SQL.

Here is something simular to map reduce in java

```
public class YourData {
    Double Low_latency;
    Dobule Max_Latency;
    int Prog_Id;

    // add getter and setter here

    public boolean tesetOverlapping(YourData data) {
        if ((this.Low_latency<=data.Low_latency && data.Low_latency<=t1.Max_Latency) ¦¦ (this.Low_latency<=data.Max_Latency && data.Max_Latency<=this.Max_Latency)) {
                this.Low_latency = Math.min(this.Low_latency, data.Low_latency);
                this.Max_Latency = Math.min(this.Max_Latency, data.Max_Latency);

                return true
        }

        return false;
    }
}

String sql = "
  SELECT
    t1.Prog_Id,
    t1.Low_latency,
    t1.Max_Latency
  FROM yourtable t1"

ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> values = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();

while (row = get sql rows) {

    int progIndex = values.indexOf(row.Prog_Id);

    if (progIndex == -1) {
        progIndex = values.indexOf(row.Prog_Id);

        values.add(progIndex, new ArrayList<Double>());
    }

    values[progIndex].add(new YourData(row));
}  

boolean foundOverlapping = false;
for (int progIndex = 0; progIndex < values.size(); progIndex++) {
    // Do map reduce for each progIndex
    do {
        foundOverlapping = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < values[progIndex].size(); i++) {
            if (!values[progIndex].contains(i)) {
                continue;
            }

            YourData cur = values[progIndex][i];

            for (int x = 0; x < values[progIndex].size(); x++) {
                if (i != x && values[progIndex].contains(x)) {
                    if (cur.tesetOverlapping(values[progIndex][x])) {
                        foundOverlapping = true;
                        values[progIndex].remove(x);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } while (foundOverlapping == true);
}
```

Comment: We can use Java. I will like to prefer in query format only, if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to group in a `-infinity...9`, `10...19`, `20...29` pattern for the lower latency, you would need something like

```
SELECT
  Prog_Id,
  MIN(Low_latency) AS Low_latency,
  MAX(Max_Latency) AS Max_Latency
FROM
  your_table_name
GROUP BY
  Prog_Id,
  IF(FLOOR(Low_latency/10)<0,0,FLOOR(Low_latency/10))
```

Obviously the last line will depend on the RDBMS used, but should be quite similar among most.

You might also want to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: This solution only groups by negative / possitiv values of low_latency and will always have max 2 rows in result set. But not realay groups overlapping ranges.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck Thanks for the reply. Can you explain the last line, if possible

Comment: @GreenRover I don't think so: The last line will create a grouping of `-infinity...9=>0`, `10...19=>1`, `20...29=>2` etc.

Comment: @user1929950 As in the comment above, the formula is designed to group in 10ms intervals (`FLOOR(Low_latency/10)` is the important part), the `IF()` is just for the negative values.

Comment: @eugen have a look at this example, here it wont work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d523e/1/0

Comment: @GreenRover The output of your SQLfiddle is exactly as wanted: (PROG_ID, LOW_LATENCY, MAX_LATENCY)=[(a,-1,8), (a,11,18), (a,22,25), (a,32,38)], so it is 4 rows: -inf...8, 11...18, 22...25, 32...38 - what is the problem?

Comment: @eugen  32-35; 36-38  should not be combined. to 32-38 because it no overlaps. The same facht is for 31-34; 37-38 to have a bigger space. This is the only problem of your query. But otherwise it realy works better as i expected

Comment: @EugenRieck I'm trying to understand how your query works, but in some situations it doesn't give the correct result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb37a/1

Comment: @EugenRieck query does not have to group low and max latency in groups of 0..9, 10..19, etc. but it has to group all overlapping values together

Comment: @GreenRover I started my answer with the assumption, that the OQ was about classifying in 10ms steps. My query works in this context - I now understand, that this assumption is wrong (English is not my first language).